# How to open notes:// url in IBM Notes client instead of IBM Notes Browser Plugin

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

I have a XPages app that contains some notes:// links to documents. The app is used in Internet Explorer which have IBM Notes Browser Plugin installed and we are not allowed to uninstall it.

Is there any option to prepare the notes:// url to enforce opening a target document in a standalone IBM Notes client instead of the plugin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you want to change it for yourself? Or for all users of the app. For just your notes:// links, or for all?

It's controlled by a registry setting: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Notes\shell\open\command`. If you have the rights, changing that setting will change it for *all* Notes links. The normal binding (without the plugin) would look something like this: `C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Notes\notes.exe" -defini "%1"`.

If you want to change the behavior for all users, but for just your app's links, I think you're going to have to use a different prefix instead of `notes://` and create a script to install the appropriate registry entries for that prefix on your users' machines. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx) for more info,

Comment: Good idea to use custom prefix (reminds me steam:// to launch their games). Mind the consequences tho, it needs some configuration work, for every user.

Comment: Thank you Richard. I have to set it for my app only so probably the script will be necessary. The main reason of it is Internet Explorer' tabs behavior. It works great without plugin installed (link opens a Notes client and a web page remains unchanged. If the plugin is installed there are two options: 1. LN is closed -> link opens a plugin (and that is ok), 2. LN is open --> link opens a doc in a LN and a webpage becomes blank (probably plugin leaves it but this is really annoying).